# binding return key in Python GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Working on a number guessing assignment for an informatics course and cannot for the life of me on this program bind this key. Using previous programs and class example I am able to bind this key to perform certain functions however not in this particular one. Therefore, I am assuming there is something super small wrong and im just overlooking it. Any help is appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *
import random

class Application(Frame):


    def __init__(self, master): #sets up gui elements
        Frame.__init__(self, master)  
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()
        self.number = random.randint(0, 9)

    def create_widgets(self):
        # creates instructions
        Label(self, text = "I'm thinking of a number between 0 and 9.").grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W)
        Label(self, text = "Try and guess it!").grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W)

        # create guess label and entry
        Label(self, text = "Your guess:").grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W)
        self.guess_ent = Entry(self)
        self.guess_ent.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W)

        # creates button to initiate run function
        self.bttn=Button(self, text = "Submit", command = self.run)
        self.bttn.grid(row = 3, column = 1, sticky = W)
        #binds return key
        self.bttn.bind('<KeyPress>', self.enter)
        self.bttn.focus_set()
        # creates feedback text box for run function
        self.text = Text(self, width = 75, height = 10, wrap = WORD)
        self.text.grid(row = 4, column = 0, columnspan = 4)



    def run(self):
        #gets random number
        guess = int(self.guess_ent.get())
    #if to test guesses and give appropriate feedback
        if guess != self.number:
            print_text = "You guessed {0}.".format(guess)

            if guess > self.number:
                print_text += " That's too high. Guess lower..."
            elif guess < self.number:
                print_text += " That's too low. Guess higher..."

            self.text.delete(0.0, END)
            self.text.insert(0.0, print_text)

            self.guess_ent.delete(0, END)
        else:
            print_text = "That's the right number! You did it!!"
            self.text.delete(0.0, END)
            self.text.insert(0.0, print_text)

    def enter(self, event):
        if event.keysym == "Return":
            self.run()
# main
root = Tk()
root.title("Number Guesser")
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return key in tkinter is also `Return`, hence your code should be :

```
self.bttn.bind('<Return>', self.enter)
```

You are binding the key to a button which does not get focus until pressed or tabbed into, making it almost impossible to notice the trigger of the binding, because your button and the bind call the same method.

Bind to the `Entry` widget such that you can trigger the binding while in the widget:

```
self.guess_ent.bind('<Return>', self.enter)
```

Comment: I hear what you're saying but it still doesn't register the key press

Comment: Ahhhhhh totally understand. I knew it was something simple I was just overlooking. Thanks!